# How do operating systems allow userspace programs to interact with kernelspace programs?

Tags: operating-system

This isn't quite a question about a specific OS, but let's take Windows as an example.  A userspace program uses the Windows API to communicate with kernelspace.  However, I don't understand how that's possible.  The API, according to MS websites, lives in userspace.  In order to access kernelspace it has to be in kernelspace, if I understand it correctly.  So what is the mechanism by which the windows API gets extra privileges to speak to kernelspace? In which space does that mechanism operate?  Is this sort of thing universal to all modern PC OS's?

Comment: Look up "system calls".

Comment: Hi,  I know that the mechanism is *called*  a system call.  My question relates to how an operating system allows information to transfer between the two memory spaces.  A system call is a function, presumably, that is compiled into a program that runs in userspace.  It shouldn't have access to kernelspace.  Why does it?  Is there a third space that is intermediate, for example?

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky Feel free for any queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the CPU that is acts as intermediate for transfer of information between user memory space(accessible in user mode) to protected memory space(accessible in kernel mode), via CPU registers.

Here's an Example:

Suppose a user writes a program in higher level language. Now when execution of the program happens, CPU generates the virtual addresses.

Now before any read/write operation occurs, the virtual address, is converted to physical address. Because the translation mechanism(memory management unit), is only accessible in kernel mode, cause its stored in protected memory, the translation occurs in kernel mode and the physical address is finally saved into some register of the CPU, and only then a read/write operation occurs.

Comment: I see.  But how does the communication go the other way?  I get that the kernelspace programs can communicate back to the userspace.  Are the registers not protected?  What happens if none are available?

Comment: General purpose registers are not protected, they are for the program there to use. In fact, every time the OS switches tasks, registers of the old task are saved, and registers of the new task are restored. Besides, not allowing the programs to use registers wouldn't make it possible to move values from one memory location to another (`mov [loc2], [loc1]` is invalid), while making everything much slower (the program would need to access the memory for almost every operation).

Comment: This answer overlooks the actual system call mechanisms used and isn't very accurate in describing the transfer of data using registers or the operation of a MMU which isn't particularly relevant to the question anyway.

Answer (score 3):

As you're already aware there a bunch of facilities exposed to userspace programs by the Windows kernel. (If you're curious [there's a list of system calls](http://j00ru.vexillium.org/ntapi/)). These system calls are all identified by a unique number, which isn't part of the publicly documented interface given by Microsoft. Instead when you call a publicly exposed function from your program there's a DLL installed when you install (or update) Windows that has an entry point which is just a normal, unprivileged user mode function call. This DLL knows the mappings between public interfaces and the available system calls in the currently running kernel. These mappings are not always 1:1 which allows for tweaks and enhancements without breaking existing code using stable interfaces.

When some userland code calls one of these functions its role is to prepare arguments for the system call and then initiate the jump into kernel mode. How exactly that jump occurs is specific to the architecture that Windows is currently running on. In fact it varies not just between x86 and Arm but between AMD and Intel x86 systems even. I'll talk just about the modern Intel x86 32-bit case (using the [SYSENTER instruction](http://wiki.osdev.org/SYSENTER)) here for simplicity. On x86 most of the other variations are relatively minor, for instance [`int 2Eh` was used prior to SYSENTER support](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=22442).

Early in boot up the operating system does a bunch of work to prepare for enabling a userland and system calls from it. Understanding this is critical to understanding how system calls really work.

First let's rewind a little and consider what exactly we mean by userland and kernelmode. On x86 when we talk about privileged vs un-privileged code we talk about "rings". There are actually 4 (ignoring hypervisors) but for various reasons nobody really used anything but ring0 (kernel) and ring3 (userland). When we run code on x86 the address that's being executed (EIP) and data that's being read/written come from segments.

Segments are mostly just a historical accident left over from the days before virtual addressing on x86 was a thing. They are however important for us here because there are special registers that define which segments are currently being used when we execute instructions or otherwise reference memory. Segments on x86 are all defined in a big table, called the Global Descriptor Table or [GDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Descriptor_Table). (There's also a local descriptor table, LDT, but that's not going to further the current discussion here). The important point for our discussion here is that the (arcane) layout of the table entries include 2 bits, called DPL which define the privilege level of the currently active segment. You'll notice that 2 bits is exactly enough to define 4 levels of privilege.

So in short when we talk about "executing in kernel mode" we really just mean that our active code segment (CS) and data segment selectors point to entries in the GDT which have DPL set to 0. Likewise for userland we have a CS and data segment selectors pointing to GDT entries with DPL set to 3 and no access to kernel addresses. (There are other selectors too, but to keep it simple we'll just consider "code" and "data" for now).

Back to early on during kernel boot up: during start up the kernel creates the [GDT entries we need](http://wiki.osdev.org/GDT_Tutorial). (These have to be laid out in a specific order for SYSENTER to work, but that's mostly just an implementation detail). There are also some "machine specific registers" that control how our processor behaves. These can only be set by privileged code. Three of them that are important here are:

- IA32_SYSENTER_ESP
- IA32_SYSENTER_EIP
- IA32_SYSENTER_CS

Recall that we've got some code runnig in userland (ring3) that wants to transition to ring0. Let's assume that it has saved any registers that it needs to per the calling convention and put arguments into the right registers that the call expects. We then hit the SYSENTER instruction. (Actually it uses `KiFastSystemCall` I think). The SYSENTER instruction is special. It modifies the current code and data segment selectors based on the value that the kernel setup in the machine specific register IA32_SYSENTER_CS. (The stack/data segument values are computed as an offset of IA32_SYSENTER_CS). Subsequently the stack pointer itself (ESP) is set to the kernel stack that was setup for handling system calls earlier on and saved into the MSR IA32_SYSENTER_ESP and likewise for EIP the instruction pointer from IA32_SYSENTER_EIP.

Since the CS selector now points to a GDT entry with DPL set to 0 and EIP points to kernel mode code on a kernel stack we're running in the kernel at this point.

From here onwards the kernel mode code can read and write memory from both kernel and userspace (with some appropriate caution) to undertake the actual work needed to perform the system call. The arguments to the system call can be read from registers etc. according to the calling convention, but any arguments that are actually pointers back to userland or handles to kernel objects can be accessed to read larger blocks of data too.

When the system call is over the process is basically reversed and we end up back in userland with DPL 3 for the selectors.